# Programatically obtaining operating system version data in Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx

In Red Hat the file `/etc/redhat-release` contains the operating system version data (such as "Red Hat release X.X (Final)").

Is there any similar mechanism in Mac OS X that can be used programatically to get the operating system version data (such as "Mac OS X 10.5.8")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are looking for more details to the kernel, you can also query the sysctl interface which provides the kernel ostype, version and other details.

- To get the ostype : **sysctl kern.ostype**
- To get the osversion : **sysctl kern.osversion**
- To get the version : **sysctl kern.version**
- To get the osrevision : **sysctl kern.osrevision**

More details here : http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html

Comment: Just FYI: On Ubuntu, it's "kernel" instead of "kern". And for these keys, the output is the same as `uname -a` (or the various subsets from other options like `-s`, `-r`, `-v`, etc.)

Comment: `uname -a` on a Mac: "Darwin <machine name>.local 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"

Comment: none of those give the OS version he wanted, e.g. 10.5.8. They give the kernel version numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

```
/usr/bin/sw_vers
```